# What do you call the cloth that this jester wears?

Tags: word-request

[image]

I am not talking about the hat, but the thing right below it that seems to be a part of the hat or separate from the hat. The hat is called a fool's cap, I think.

Comment: Are you talking about his collar?

Comment: I've looked at other images of jesters online. In some, the vandyked (cut into points) garment is a narrow collar, in others it extends over the shoulders like a cape. I don't know if there is an official name for it.